# Adding An Object To A CoreData Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, one-to-many, nsset

Hello once again friends,

I am writing a coreData app that has a one to many relationship.

[image]

And I have the function:

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    ...
    print("\(self.timeSlotSet!.timeSlots)\n")
    self.timeSlot!.timeSlotSet = self.timeSlotSet!
    print("\(self.timeSlotSet!.timeSlots)\n")
    ...
    self.timeSlotSet!.calculateNumberOfItems()
    print("\(self.timeSlotSet!.timeSlotCount!)\n")


}
```

where the calculateNumerOfItems function is:

```
func calculateNumberOfItems() {
    timeSlotCount = timeSlots!.count
}
```

which prints the following results to console:

```
Optional(Relationship 'timeSlots' on managed object (0x7ca721e0) <TimeSlotSet: 0x7ca721e0> (entity: TimeSlotSet; id: 0x7be40040 <x-coredata://39B379DC-2F28-42FE-9716-084A4769CD40/TimeSlotSet/p2> ; data: {
    name = nil;
    test = 0;
    timeSlotCount = 0;
    timeSlots =     (
    );
}) with objects {(
)})

Optional(Relationship 'timeSlots' on managed object (0x7ca721e0) <TimeSlotSet: 0x7ca721e0> (entity: TimeSlotSet; id: 0x7be40040 <x-coredata://39B379DC-2F28-42FE-9716-084A4769CD40/TimeSlotSet/p2> ; data: {
    name = nil;
    test = 0;
    timeSlotCount = 0;
    timeSlots =     (
        "0x7be5a9d0 <x-coredata://39B379DC-2F28-42FE-9716-084A4769CD40/TimeSlot/p1>"
    );
}) with objects {(
    <TimeSlot: 0x7be3c2e0> (entity: TimeSlot; id: 0x7be5a9d0 <x-coredata://39B379DC-2F28-42FE-9716-084A4769CD40/TimeSlot/p1> ; data: {
    beginDate = "2015-12-26 12:20:43 +0000";
    currentSeconds = 2;
    endDate = "2015-12-26 12:20:46 +0000";
    timeSlotSet = "0x7be40040 <x-coredata://39B379DC-2F28-42FE-9716-084A4769CD40/TimeSlotSet/p2>";
})
)})

0
```

I am having difficulty wording this... but:

I believed this line:
        self.timeSlot!.timeSlotSet = self.timeSlotSet!
created the relationship between TimeSlotSet and TimeSlot - and added one timeSlot to TimeSlotSet's timeSlots attribute (which is an NSSet)

I also believe it is successful because when I print the timeSlotSet to console it is different after I have committed this line. (Right?)

Then why is timeSlotCount still 0?
Does that not imply that timeSlots is still empty?

Also, do I have to save the timeSlot to persistent storage, or can I just save the TimeSlotSet? I want to save both. Do I have to explicitly save both? Or does saving one save both? (since they have a relationship between the two)

The end goal is that I can save many TimeSlot items to the TimeSlotSet and then iterate over its timeSlots NSSet and create algorithms for all these TimeSlot objects.

Thank you - I hope I wrote this correctly. Am I conceptually wrong anywhere? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `timeslotCount` be `self.timeslotSet.timeslotCount`? Also, do you really need that variable? Shouldn't you just use the `timeslotSet.timeslots.count`? This will eliminate the need for a separate function.

For your other question, you usually save the entire context. This will save all new objects as well as all changes to existing objects.